# EntityFramework Core Union Select - Null Related Data

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

To get a better picture, I am trying to have a feed composed from different Elements (I'll try to make the example as short as possible) :

```
public class FeedDTO
    {
        public int Type { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public CommentDTO Comment { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public LikeDTO Like { get; set; }

        public static FeedDTO SetComment(Comment comment, int userId)
        {
            return new FeedDTO
            {
                Type = ACTIVITY_FEED_TYPE.COMMENT,
                Date = comment.CreateDate,
                Comment = comment.Adapt(userId)
            };
        }

        public static FeedDTO SetLike(Like like, int userId)
        {
            return new FeedDTO
            {
                Type = ACTIVITY_FEED_TYPE.LIKE,
                Date = like.CreateDate,
                Like = like.Adapt(userId)
            };
        }
    }
```

And here is where I try to query the data :

```
public IQueryable<FeedDTO> Feed(int userId)
        {

            var listComments =
                Context.Comments
                    /* includes ... */
                    .Select(x => FeedDTO.SetComment(x, userId));

            var listLikes =
                Context.Likes
                    /* includes ... */
                    .Select(x => FeedDTO.SetLike(x, userId));

            return listLikes.Union(listComments).OrderByDescending(x => x.Date);

}
```

---

The issue is :

- When I return each one alone, without `Union` it works
- When I try to `Union` all the related data in the FeedDTO methods are `null`

Comment: If the classes `Comment` and `Like` are database entities, aren't you getting an exception like "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method SetLike()" ? Because that can't be converted to an SQL query.

Comment: No, because there is methods "Adapt" in the database entity, and we construct the DTO from a .Select(comment => comment.Adapt()) so there is no issue with that,
As I said, each list alone is working fine, the issue is when we try to concat 'Union' the results.

Comment: Well, there is the problem because before calling `Union()` the query is not being run. If you debug it and put a breakpoint after the declaration of `listComments` and you try to expand the results, it will give that exception in the debugger regardless of the `Adapt` method. But if you do this: `Context.Comments.ToList()...` it will not do so because that way it will not be translated to an SQL query.

Comment: @granit I know, the thing is, I can't load all the data and order the items so I can get  paginate it. I am trying to find a solution for this, otherwise I will have to make a SQL stored procedure and get directly the response.

Comment: @KhalilBhm Did you find a solution to this? I have come across the same issue